# Applying webkit transitions to span classes?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've seen a similar question asked, but the solutions wouldn't work for how I was using the span classes. In effect, I'm using the span classes as alternate text for a hover. I'd like to ease in / ease out the classes on hover, but I can't figure out where to apply the webkit or what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mdmg2"><span class="alias">name</span> <span class="infor">age / tz / pm</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mdmg2 { text-transform: lowercase; color: #fff; text-align: left; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black, 1px 1px 0px white, 1px 1px 0px black; }
.mdmg2 .infor { display: none; }
.mdmg2:hover .alias { display: none; }
.mdmg2:hover .infor { display: inline; font-size: 30px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: montserrat; position: relative; top: -10px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Interpretation

As I understand it, you want `.alias` to be shown when `.mdmg2` is **not** hovered, and for `.infor` to be shown when it **is** hovered. You want to fade in-between the two.

### Your Problem

You **cannot** animate the `display` property, and thus if you want to fade content it is not going to be suitable. However, there is a CSS property called `opacity`. This can be set to any decimal between `0` and `1`, which corresponds to a percentage value of how opaque the element is (i.e. how transparent it is).

This property **can** be animated, so we change the `display` styles to use `opacity` instead, and add in the proper code to perform the animation. Although OP asked for webkit transitions, there is no vendor prefix for transition (see http://caniuse.com/#search=transition), so the property is just `transition`. You can read about it's syntax and how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Now, there is an animation on-hover, but unlike `display`, using opacity the old object still takes up space on the page; i.e. the two `spans` are not in the same space. This is obviously not right, and so to fix this, we set a width on `.alias` (`100px`). This ensures that `.alias` will **always** take up `100px`, so we can move `.infor` to `100px` to the right to ensure that the two elements line up.

### Solution

Thus, the complete solution to your issue is:

```css
.mdmg2 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black, 1px 1px 0px white, 1px 1px 0px black;
  position:relative;
}
.mdmg2 .infor {
  opacity:0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: montserrat;
  transition:opacity 0.5s;
  position:relative;
  left:-100px;
}
.mdmg2 .alias {
  opacity:1;
  transition:opacity 0.5s;
  width:100px;
}
.mdmg2:hover .infor {
  opacity:1;
}
.mdmg2:hover .alias {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdmg2"><span class="alias">name</span> <span class="infor">age / tz / pm</span></div>
```